# how to get String in non context class of android from @String

Tags: java, android

how to get String in non context class of android from @String ?

my class is an adapter class and i am not using any context object in it.

Comment: use one constant class and declare static variable in it and use.

Comment: As stated, you'll need to pass a context to your adapter. Then use `context.getResources().getString(R.id.mystring);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pass a context in.

The way you get to the @String values is by using the method `Context.getResources()`.

My suggestion would be to keep a private field that holds the context, and initialise it in your adapter's constructor.